# Multiple inheritance in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mixins

Multiple inheritance in Ruby is simulated by including modules, but it's not possible to inherit properties directly from modules (that are not classes). The solution I came up was to define properties on the module initialization (code below). Is there a better way to achieve multiple inheritance compared the code below (inheriting methods AND properties)?

```
module MyCustomMixin
    attr_accessor :a

    def initialize
        self.a = 1
    end

    def b
        "something"
    end
end

class MyCreateView < CreateView
    include MyCustomMixin
end

class MyReadView < ReadView
    include MyCustomMixin
end

class MyUpdateView < UpdateView
    include MyCustomMixin
end

class MyDeleteView < DeleteView
    include MyCustomMixin
end
```

Comment: Ruby doesn't have properties. What are you talking about?

Comment: I mean _attribute_. I'm sorry if they have different names across languages, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: Ruby doesn't have attributes either. "Attribute" is simply given a name to a method that doesn't take arguments. It's still a method just like any other.

Comment: So the `b` method in `MyCustomMixin` acts as an attribute, because all it does is return a value.

Comment: Yes. You could also define a method `b=` to make it a writeable "attribute".

Comment: But it's no better than defining it as `attr_accessor` and setting it's default value on `initialize`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the same. But the premise of your question is that methods are inherited and properties aren't, but they are one and the same!

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, this is *technically* doable, but it requires a bit of finagling that doesn't look very pretty (especially with `#initialize`) - and rightfully so. I wouldn't recommend writing code in this way if the only purpose is to prevent code repetition.

So, consider:

- What's the reason for having a `MyFooView` version for every `FooView`? Is it just to include mixins?
- Perhaps all the `View`s have a common parent to which you could add this mixin?
- Does the mixin contain functionality that is used in things other than `View`? Why not just add it directly to the parent `View`?
- If the mixin is really that independent of the `View` classes, why isn't it just a class in itself, so that each `View` would own an instance of it?

Comment: I came up with this question because I have a Python background (Python supports multiple inheritance, which is often used to apply mixins. Example: http://bit.ly/1kxoaMI).

I'm also a C#/PHP developer, and your suggestions may be applied to them as well, so my conclusion is that Ruby's inheritance model is not that that different from these languages.